# Azure Kusto :: Convert Time in 12 Hour Format to 24 Hour Format

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to convert the following 12 hour time format to 24 time format using Azure Kusto language. I would expect the output to be converted from 07:00:00 AM to 07:00:00 and 07:00:00 PM to 19:00:00. Executing the below query is not resulting into correct output, sure i am missing something. Can anyone help please.

```
datatable (Date:string, Event:string)
    ['07:00:00 AM', "Morning",
     '07:00:00 PM', "Evening"]
     | extend val = todatetime(Date), val2 = format_datetime(todatetime(strcat('1900-01-01, ',Date)),'HH:mm:ss')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**a.** if you want to create a `datetime` value, you could try something like this:

- parse the parts out of the string (hours, minutes, ...).
- adjust the `hours` part to be in 24-hour format
- create a `datetime` value out of those, using `make_datetime()`, or using [datetime / timespan arithmetic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datetime-timespan-arithmetic).

for example:

```
datatable (TimeOfDay:string, Event:string)
[
    '07:00:01 AM', "Morning",
    '07:01:23 PM', "Evening"
]
| parse TimeOfDay with hours:int ":" minutes:int ":" seconds:int " " am_pm
| extend hours = case(am_pm == "AM" and hours == 12, hours - 12,
                      am_pm == "AM", hours,
                      hours == 12, hours,
                      hours + 12)
| project dt = make_datetime(1970, 1, 1, hours, minutes, seconds) // just used 1970-01-01 for the example
```

**b.** otherwise, if you just want to create a string value, you could do something somewhat similar:

```
datatable (TimeOfDay:string, Event:string)
[
    '07:00:01 AM', "Morning",
    '07:01:23 PM', "Evening"
]
| parse TimeOfDay with hours:int ":" minutes_seconds " " am_pm
| extend hours = case(am_pm == "AM" and hours == 12, tostring(hours),
                      am_pm == "AM", strcat("0", hours),
                      hours == 12, tostring(hours),
                      tostring(hours + 12))
| project str = strcat(hours, ":", minutes_seconds)
```